# Scala tool similar to Linqpad

Tags: scala, linqpad

So I'm a huge fan of LinqPad, but not just for its little LINQ testing but for quick scratchpad development using C# or F# since it adds REPL to C#.  Anyways, I know scala has an interactive windows but is there any sort of lightweight tool similar to LinqPad that will work with Scala?  Or is there some other great, light-weight, tool for prototyping in scala?

Comment: What do you mean by *interactive windows*? Scala has [REPL](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2097) as well, are you looking for something different?

Comment: +1  
Unfortunately, AFAIK, there is no standalone GUI tool like LinqPad, but you can use scala REPL with [SIQ](http://code.google.com/p/scala-integrated-query/) (closest analog to LINQ in my opinion). [Here](http://scala-integrated-query.googlecode.com/files/SIQ-Scala-Days-final.pdf) is the usage (pdf file!) of SIQ.

Comment: I use the REPL, or if it's a bit more complex, add a file to my "odds and ends" project in IntelliJ. There are a few programs that people have written to sit on top of the REPL but I haven't found them particularly useful. I don't expect people have put much effort in because using an IDE is easy.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I count three standalone GUI tools, why don't they qualify?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral cause all of them (ScalaConsole, Scalide and ScalaEdit) are kinds of REPL. I thought about scala powered _database interacting_ GUI tools (yep, this work could be done with REPL, and GUI REPL wrappers too, but they will not bring any specilized functionality).

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz the one thing that I was looking for was more of a scratchpad for a small program (e.g. write a few lines, run it, fix the little mistake, run again) without requiring a full on IDE or project definition (in linqpad I don't even have to save the files).

Answer (score 4):

[Scala-ide](http://www.scala-ide.org/) has a built in repl that is graphical, (it does not fit the lightweight part of your question). Try it by pressing `Ctrl-Shift-X` inside a Scala editor to run the selected expression (or the current line). [Here is how it looks like](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/Run_Selection_Interpreter). I think it is the closest thing right now.

[image]

[Kojo](http://kogics.net/sf:kojo) is based on scala, but not really what you are asking for either but cool, and could be used for learning purposes.

[image]

Also in the Scala Plugin for [IntelliJ IDEA (Nika builds)](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+Nika) Scala Language Console

[image]

**Web**

On the web there is at least two consoles

[Simplex3dConsole](http://www.simplex3d.org/console/) (Java Web Start)
[image]

http://www.simplyscala.com/? (Web based)

For a SQL based console written in scala have a look at [SQLShell](https://github.com/bmc/sqlshell) adding something like that to repl or sbt or a graphical tool. Se also [Scala integrated query](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/ScalaDays+2011+Resources#ScalaDays2011Resources-ScalaIntegratedQuery-moreexpressivedatabasequeries) which might interest you.

Comment: Yeah I really like the scala-ide plugin but it runs in eclipse... and that is not lightweight at all.  But it is probably the best ide for scala development (I like it better then intellij scala plugin).

Comment: the simplex3dconsole is kind of what I was looking for, although it does feel a little lacking compared to the power of linqpad for those languages, and I love simplyscala it was the site that got me started but it is just a regular REPL.

Answer (score 2):

**Zeppelin**

http://zeppelin-project.org is web-based scala REPL with Apache Spark support.
It's an Apache2 license opensource.

[image: here is an screenshot]

**Scala Notebook**

Scala Notebook is another notebook style web-based scala REPL.

https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries#ToolsandLibraries-Miscellaneous): [ScalaConsole](http://code.google.com/p/scala-console/), [Scalide](http://code.google.com/p/scalide/) and [ScalaEdit](http://code.google.com/p/scala-edit/). Though, of course, you also have REPL on the IDEs, and also from SBT. Oh, and [Kojo](http://kogics.net/sf%3akojo).